# How to add files for the ec2 instance which is launched with autoscaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I see we can add files to the ec2 instance by Metadata with Cloudformation:Init as follows.

```
"Resources": {
 "MyInstance": {
"Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
"Metadata" : {
  "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
    "config" : {
      "packages" : {
        :
      },
      "groups" : {
        :
      },
      "users" : {
        :
      },
      "sources" : {
        :
      },
      "files" : {
        :
      },
      "commands" : {
        :
      },
      "services" : {
        :
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
 }

But when I want to launch an instance with autoscaling group, How can I do it? I have tried that add Metadata under Launch configuration as EC2.

Answer (score 1):

Include the `Metadata` structure in your `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration` resource which is used by your Auto Scaling group.

```
"LaunchConfig" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
  "Metadata" : {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
      "config" : {
        "files" : {
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Properties" : {
  }
}
```

There is a sample here which does it:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/AutoScalingMultiAZWithNotifications.template

Take a look at the "LaunchConfig" resource.

Comment: I tried your template. But I didn't find out the files when I ssh to the instance.

Comment: That could be for many reasons. Post your launch configuration so we can see it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forget to run the cfn-init before checking the files.
Now it works well when I use an AMI with `centos`, but it didn't work when I use an AMI with `ubuntu` after installed `aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest`. The error is `cfn-init -v -s test-stack1 -r MigratorLaunchConfig --region ap-southeast-2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cfn-init", line 22, in <module>
    from heat_cfntools.cfntools import cfn_helper
ImportError: No module named heat_cfntools.cfntools`

Answer (score 0):

Now, It works well. I can run the command `cfn-int -s <stack_name> -r <resource> --region ..` to sync the resource after the ec2 was launched.